# JCombobox - no success adding 2d String-array when parameterized

Tags: java, swing, generics, jcombobox

If I instanciate the JCombobox-class of Swing and add String[][]-items to it - there is no problem except that I get the following warning:

JComboBox is a raw type. References to generic type JComboBox  should be parametirized.

Well - I parameterize the object in the following manner

```
private JComboBox <String[][]> myComboBox = new JComboBox <String[][]> ();
```

It looks good at first because the warning dissappears, but I get an error when I want to add items from the String[][]-object

```
 myComboBox.addItem(this.stringList[i][1]);
```

*errormessage:*

```
 *the method addItem(String[][]) in the type JComboBox <String[][]> is not applicable for the arguments (String).*
```

**What did I do wrong and how do I solve it?**

*By the way - if you have time to answer more - Is there a danger/drawback using rawtypes?*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, when you parametrize `JComboBox` with `<String[][]>`, the method `addItem()` requires a `String[][]` as a parameter:

```
public void addItem(String[][] item) { // method signature when <String[][]>
```

In your example you are trying to pass a normal `String`, which is obviously not allowed, since it is not a `String[][]`.

To fix this issue, just parametrize it with `String`:

```
private JComboBox<String> myComboBox = new JComboBox<>();
```

For more information about rawtypes see the amazingly detailled answer to that question: 
[What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

Comment: I assume `stringList` is a `String[][]` so it contains `String`s. When doing `stringList[i][1]` you get the `String` in row *i* and column *1*. If you really want to add the whole array just do `add(stringList);`. The error message actually says that you are trying to add a `String`.